# Vs code extensions does not stay installed

Tags: visual-studio-code

Everytime i close vscode all the extensions become uninstalled. I have to install them everytime i open vscode. Sometimes even while i am working all the extansions give "requires reinstall" message.

I've uninstalled and installed vscode and tried to disable - enable extensions on command pallete. Still the same.

Comment: Possibly related: [VS Code does not recognize file extensions. Can't install any extensions](/q/75447496/11107541)